# What is the best framework to connect mysql from c++?

Tags: c++, mysql

Is there some kind of c++ framework that wrappers the c++ driver ? 
So it will give me API to connect mysql and run sql queries?

Answer (score 4):

You should check out [MySql++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/)

Comment: what is the difference between mysql-connector-c++ from MySql site and this framework?

Comment: @user63898: That's answered in the MySQL++ FAQ, right on the front page: http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/#conncpp